# what's wrong with this exercise using Stokes' Theorem?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, stokes-theorem

The exercise asks to verify Stokes' Theorem for the field $F (x, y, z) = (y ^ 2 + z, x + z ^ 2, x^2+y)$ on the surface generated by the rotation of the curve $ y = x^2 $ with $ 1 \leq x \leq 2 $ around the $x$ axis.

I start by checking that $ \text{rot}\ F (x, y, z) = (1 - 2z, 1-2x, 1-2y)$
and I notice that the parametrization of the revolution surface is $r(t, \theta) = (t,t^2\cos(\theta), t^2\sin(\theta))$ with $1 \leq t \leq 2$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$.

[image]

Then $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial t}(t, \theta) \times \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial \theta}(t, \theta) = (1, 2t \cos(\theta), 2t \sin(\theta)) \times (0, -t^2 \cos(\theta), t^2 \cos(\theta)) = (2t^3, -t^2\cos(\theta), -t^2 \sin(\theta)),$ and then,
\begin{align}
\iint_S \text{rot}\ F \cdot dS &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{1}^{2} \text{rot}\ F(r(t, \theta)) \cdot (2t^3,-t^2\cos(\theta), -t^2 \sin(\theta)) dt d\theta\\
& = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{1}^{2} (1 - 2[t^2\sin(\theta)], 1-2t, 1-2[t^2\cos(\theta)]) \cdot (2t^3, -t^2\cos(\theta), -t^2\sin(\theta)) dt d\theta = 15 \pi.
\end{align}
On the other hand, the $ S $ surface boundary is formed by two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$, $C_1$ centered on $(1,0,0)$ with radius $1$, and $C_2$ centered on $(2,0,0)$ with radius $2$, both located in planes parallel to the YZ plane.
The parametrizations of $ C_1 $ and $ C_2 $ are respectively $r_1(t) = (1, \cos(t), \sin(t))$ and $r_2(t) = (2, \cos(t), \sin(t))$ with $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_{C_1 \cup C_2}F \cdot dr &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}F(r_1(t)) \cdot r_1'(t)dt+\int_{0}^{2\pi}F(r_2(t)) \cdot r_2'(t)dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos^2(t)+\sin(t), 1+ \sin^2(t), 1+\cos(t)) \cdot (0, -\sin(t), \cos(t)) dt+  \int_{0}^{2\pi}(4\cos^2(t)+2\sin(t), 2+ 4\sin^2(t), 4+2\cos(t)) \cdot (0, -2\sin(t), 2\cos(t)) dt = 5\pi.
\end{align}

strangely, it resulted $\iint_S \text{rot}\ F \cdot dS \neq \int_{C_1 \cup C_2}F \cdot dr$. I checked the calculations and there doesn't seem to be an error in the accounts, there must be some error in some parametrization, but I'm not noticing the error, can someone point me out?

Comment: I didn't calculate, so there may be things I've missed. But the radius of $C_2$ ought to be $2^2 = 4$, and you need to take the orientation into account, one circle is traversed "clockwise", the other "counterclockwise".

Comment: It must be exactly there that I got lost, because usually the frontier of the exercises is only one, then it becomes easier for you to reference the orientation with respect to the normal vector.

Comment: @DanielFischer Observing what you said, I noticed that the value of the line integral is $ -3 \pi $, so the error must be in calculating the surface integral.

Comment: Calculating the surface area of your surface of revolution in two ways yields the same result, so that leads me to believe that your parametrization is correct. Curl is computed correctly. For the surface integral, I compute $\frac{137 \pi} 5.$ For the integral over the boundary, I compute $-3 \pi.$ I cannot tell what went wrong.

Comment: it really is very strange!